# Copy Paste Dynamic Range Based on Text in Column A

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, copy-paste

am looking to copy a dynamic range of cells that are between rows defined by two text strings. For example from the row in column A containing "Start" to the row in column A containing "End". The copied range is dynamic in its column and row count. There are some blank rows between start and end and their copying is not necessary.

Have started with the following but this only is because it is always at the top of the sheet.

Sub CopyTest()

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("The Wall Raw Data")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("Test Sheet")

ws1.Range("A3").Copy ws2.Range("A1")
ws1.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Copy ws2.Range("A3")
```

End Sub

Comment: This is very vague about where the location information is coming from. Also note that your code samples will present more cleanly if you put a line with three backticks ``` before and after.

Comment: Was able to apply a solution to a similar problem so I think it is resolved, thanks